# When creating a new object why does it update the old one?

Tags: javascript, object, scoping

When i create a new object from an existing object, then append a new attribute, why does it update the earlier one?

Is their a solution that does not involve changing my code much?

[Here is my example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qS4XZ/1/).

```
var data = [
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "carrot",
    "price" : 0.10,
    "stock" : 12,
    "bgLocation" : "-1px -54px"
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "fennel",
    "price" : 1.20,
    "stock" : 6,
    "bgLocation" : "-146px -52px"    
  }
]

var item = data[0];
item.added = 4;

//data[0] should not contain the added attribute.
$('body').append(JSON.stringify(data[0]));
```

Comment: It must be once again a matter of copy by reference...

Comment: @sp00m Can you explain how I would directly copy, rather than reference it?

Comment: You not the only one who's looking for that job, [obviously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7486130/1225328) `;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all you get is a *reference* to the original object, *not* a copy. Thus, if you update this reference, you are implicitly updating the original object.

You can easily create a copy using [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var item = $.extend({}, data[0]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qS4XZ/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks for that, this is the simplest solution to my problem. Ill mark as accepted when I can. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

The variables **item** and **data** are just references pointing to the same object. By calling.

```
var item = data[0];
```

you're not copying the object, you just create a new reference on the object that is addressed with **data[0]**. Therefore

```
item.added = 4;
```

will change the object bot vraiables point to.

Here

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

are some detailed information on how to copy objects in javascript.